# how to get word from string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

I have multiple string which contains HP16SDA305009, HP16JDA305009,HP16SWA305009

I need to get only SDA, JDA or SWA
how can I achieve that

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is there allways `HP16` before and `305009`  after?

Comment: when you want to use Regex, this site can help you a lot https://regexr.com/

Comment: @Toto no not always HP16

Comment: @Melody Thanks for the useful link...:)

Comment: You are welcome, this site helped me a lot when I started with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = "HP16SDA305009";

 $result = substr($var, 0, -6);

echo $result = substr($result, 4, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

$a=  'HP16JDA305009';

```
        $char = substr($a, 4, -3);

        echo $gen = substr($char, 0, 3);
```